# Find depth of each children of body in an HTML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In the below code sample, Body has two children. I would like to know the max depth of each child
Body element has two children nodes, how do I find each child's max depth. 
Here in this case: 
Child 1 depth: 3
Child 2 depth: 5

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>    
</body>
```

Comment: Did you like my response?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery it is quite straight forward although your question isn't clear.

```
$('.child-2').parents().length
```

or this If you use calcDepth your question isn't clear.

```
var calcDepth = function ( root ) {
    var $children = $( root ).children();
    var depth = 0;

    while ( $children.length > 0 ) {
        $children = $children.children();
        depth += 1;
    }

    return depth;
};
var result = calcDepth( document.getElementById('parent-1') );
```

Comment: Firts one doesn't do what is asked